# Does the category of posets have pushouts and pullbacks?

Tags: ct.category-theory, order-theory, posets

Let $\mathbf{Poset}$ be the category of partially ordered sets with order-preserving maps. Does $\mathbf{Poset}$ have both pushouts and pullbacks?

Comment: Yes. See http://mathoverflow.net/q/91377.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is complete and cocomplete because it is locally presentable. Of course, a colimit of posets will "crush" all loops because of antisymmetry. In particular, it has pushouts and pullbacks.